# Print `ggplot2` shape in text of rmarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

Please consider the following:

For a report written in `bookdown` (both HTML and PDF), I want to refer to a shape I use in a `ggplot2` figure. In `rmarkdown` we can refer to an `object` or R code inline by calling `` `r object` ``.

---

**Question:** How can we "print" a `ggplot2` `shape` inline?

---

**Example**
The following figure depicts a standard boxplot for the variable `cyl` from the `mtcars` dataset. Depicting the data mean is not a standard but nice to have. Here, the mean is added to the boxplot using `shape` number 23.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = disp, group = cyl)) +
        geom_boxplot() +
        stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", shape = 23, size = 3) +
        facet_wrap(~ cyl, scales = "free")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

In my text, I want to explicitly refer to this `shape` inline by writing something like:

"`` `r print(shape == 23)` `` refers to the mean of cyl [...]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use unicode to represent the shape within the text:

```
`r knitr::asis_output("\U20DF ")` refers to the mean of cyl [...]
```

[image: rmarkdown render]

**Edit:**
I should note that if you are using Rstudio and knitting to HTML, you can just paste the unicode symbol directly into your rmd file (this probably makes more sense than the original answer I posted).

```r
◇ refers to the mean of cyl [...]
```

It should work if you are knitting to pdf, but your mileage may vary depending on your OS and latex install.

Comment: Thanks! Is there an 'easy' way to look-up the unicode of a shape? How did you find it?

Comment: I suppose unicode standards might be the way to go: https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U25A0.pdf